# Why await stops further execution without throwing error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, next.js, async-await, react-query

Within React hook I have defined async function. That function calls another function and awaits the result. Await call is wrapped in `try .. catch .. finally` block. For some reason in some cases, when code execution reaches await - it stops.

Code looks more or less like this:

```
const useCustomHook = () = {
   const searchMutation = useSearchMutation();

   const onSearch = async (searchParams: ISearchParams) => {
      try {
         // some code
         const resposnse = await searchMutation({params});
         // handling results
      } catch (error) { 
         // some code
      } finally { 
         // some code
      }
   }

   return { onSearch };
}
```

`SearchMutation` is another hook which wraps request execution using `react-query`:

```
const mutatePromise = async (variables: Variables, options?: IMutationOptions<Data, Error, Variables>) => {
    return new Promise<Data>((resolve, reject) => {
        result.mutate(variables, {
            ...options,
            onSuccess: data => {
                resolve(data);
            },
            onError: error => {
                reject(error);
            },
        });
    });
};
```

`result.mutate` call is executing custom mutation function:

```
const result = _useMutation<Data, Error, Variables>({
        mutationKey: url,
        mutationFn: async variables => {
            const method = options?.method || "POST";
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method,
                headers: {
                    Accept: options?.accept || "application/json",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: variables ? JSON.stringify(variables) : undefined,
            });

            if (options?.accept === "text/csv") {
                const filename = getFilenameFromHeaders(response.headers);
                const blob = await response.blob();
                downloadFile(blob, filename);
                return;
            } else {
                const contentLength = Number(response.headers.get("Content-Length"));
                if (contentLength > 0) {
                    const responseValue = await response.json();
                    if ((responseValue?.hasOwnProperty("isSuccess") && !responseValue.isSuccess) || !response.ok) {
                        throw responseValue;
                    }

                    return responseValue;
                }
            }

            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error();
            }
        },
        ...options,
    });
```

In some specific cases (when multiple calls are executed in short period of time) `onSuccess` function is resolved with `undefined` value. In this case `onSearch` function stops execution of code after awaiting `searchMutation` function call.

How is it possible? Resolving promise with undefined shouldn't prevent further code execution after all. Moreover no error is thrown. It just silently stops...

Do you have at least any hints how to debug such issue?

Comment: Are you sure it’s because it’s resolved with `undefined`? That behavior is more indicative of not calling `onSuccess` or `onError` at all.

Comment: What is `result.mutate`?

Comment: @Bergi result is useMutation from react-query, and result.mutate is custom mutation function performing request.

Comment: @ArkadiuszKałkus That's what I thought - please post the code of your custom mutation function

Comment: @Ry- Indeed onSuccess is not called enough times! It seems something is - as Bergi suggested wrong with custom mutation function...

Comment: @Bergi I've updated the question with custom mutation function code.

Comment: Instead of returning new promise in `mutatePromise` function I've just called `result.mutateAsync(variables, options)` and it fixed the problem. It seems the implementation of promise was broken, but I don't know in what way...

Comment: I would recommend to add `console.log` on every major step across all these functions to see which sequence of steps leads to infinite wait. It is not possible that a `promise` is fulfilled but `await` keeps waiting. I would rather think that `mutationFn` doesn't exit properly. Fill it with `console.logs` on every step and especially before each `return`, `throw`, e.t.c. and I'm sure you will find something.

Comment: My guess is that `useMutation` does not call `onSuccess` if the component was unmounted, a subsequent `mutate()` call was already made, or something like that. When using the promise returned by `mutateAsync()`, the calling code is responsible for that itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by this part of the code:

```
return new Promise<Data>((resolve, reject) => {
    result.mutate(variables, {
        ...options,
        onSuccess: data => {
            resolve(data);
        },
        onError: error => {
            reject(error);
        },
    });
});
```

For some reason, which is still unclear to me, it didn't call `resolve` nor `reject`. Replacing it with `result.mutateAsync(variables, options)` solved the problem.